# vscodce's IntelliSense doesn't work with ":" as prefix of a snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code

Created this snippet:

```
"data-hook": {
        "prefix": ":",
        "body": [
          ": '[data-hook=\"\"]'"
        ],
        "description": "Just a shortcut for a data-hook selector creation",
      }
```

and when using colon on a file in the project, vscode won't suggest the snippet.
Only if I use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> (macOS) I'll see the snippet suggestion.
When I use other prefixes the snippet works fine.
does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: this works on windows

Comment: weird. for me it doesn't

Comment: did you change any default configuration values on your VSC

Comment: Actually I didn't

Comment: have you check the Mac VSC doc? `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/snippets?view=vsmac-2019`

Comment: I checked - didn't help :/

Comment: which works perfectly on my mac. will you try to uninstall and install the VSC

Comment: Just doesn't work in any of the vsc of my team members..

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to fix this issue. the problem might occure because Intellisense is getting in the way or else default putting your new snippet to the bottom of the list. to overcome the issue you can place the following code on top of your file

```
{
  "editor.tabCompletion": true,
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
}
```

Comment: someone already suggested this on another thread, it's not the solution.
placed it in the settings.json filed, and nothing changed.
still seeing the intellisense only after command+i.